# Is a script running inside command substitution?

Tags: command-substitution

In a POSIX-compatible shell, is it possible to determine if a script is running inside command substitution?

```
my-outer $(my-inner)  $(my-other-inner)
```

For the above example, `my-inner` and `my-other-inner` would need to determine if inside command substitution.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why would it matter that a script is running inside command substitution? Do you need to differentiate between `$(foo)` ` foo | bar`? between `$(foo)` and `<(foo)`? etc.

Comment: I saw it done differently in an other shell (Fish: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/functions/psub.fish#L49), and I was curious how it was done in BASH/KSH/MKSH. Right now I don't need it. It's mainly for curiosity and learning purposes.

Comment: I would only need to know if script is in `$(foo)`.  Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, not realy.

Your question boil down to : am I running `foobar` from "main" shell or `echo $(foobar)` (command substitution) ?

`foobar` may test the following

- `tty` (am I under a tty ? )
- `$SHLVL` (how many stack of shell ? )

Depending on your need, you may store and compare `SHLVL` var, this supposed you (your shell) are the one that run the command.

I put quote arroud main, because there is no such thing as main shell, you have loggin shell (with a tty), shell forked from cron, daemons (mails, apache), but no "main" shell.

edit:

as pointed SHLVL might be tricky to use

```
archemar@home> cat t2.sh
echo "$SHLVL" $1
archemar@home> . ./t2.sh $SHLVL
3 3
archemar@home> ./t2.sh $SHLVL
4 3
archemar@home> ./t2.sh $(./t2.sh)
4 4
archemar@home>
```

Comment: `$SHLVL` won't work. Try `echo 'echo "$SHLVL"' > /tmp/test.sh; echo "$(sh /tmp/test.sh)"`.

Comment: `$SHLVL`  doesn't distinguish between command-substitution and any other kind of sub-shell.

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`, check `cmdsubst` string is existed inside [`zsh_eval_context` array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-zsh_005feval_005fcontext):

```
$ echo "$(
  c=cmdsubst
  if (($zsh_eval_context[(Ie)$c])); then
    echo inside cmdsubst
  fi
)"
inside cmdsubst
```